# How to fix duplication of dynamic input creation at press of hotkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a legacy barcode scanning application, which is used to issue items from the store. It has a combo box which has a list of all pending orders and when the user selects an order, it will list out the items expected to be issued with their quantities. Then the user presses 'f7' as a shortcut key and a new barcode field is added dynamically and then they have to scan the barcode of the bin location and after it is validated, automatically another field for the item code is added dynamically. After the item code is validated, the quantity field is added dynamically wherein the user inputs the quantity taken from that bin location. The user presses 'f7' again and the process repeats unless they finish collecting the items.

At last, they save the order and proceeds with another order.

The problem which I am facing right now is that the number of times user selects the order and presses 'f7', that number of fields are added automatically.

Example, the first time when the page loads, the user selects the order, presses 'f7', one field for bin location is added automatically, no issue here. Now, due to some reason, the user selects a second order and presses 'f7', now 2 bin location fields are added automatically. The user selects third order and presses 'f7', now 3 bin location fields are added automatically. This goes on repeating unless the user refreshes the page and starts new.

There is a variable `serial` defined which I have tried resetting at the time of user selecting the order but the problem still exists. I have tried resetting the variable at different places, but the problem doesn't go away.

I have used hotkeys javascript to use 'f7' as the shortcut

https://unpkg.com/hotkeys-js@3.7.1/dist/hotkeys.js

During the HTML load, a select input box is populated with all the pending orders and the below code calls the function `ValueChanged` with the order number when the value is changed:

`<select name="Request" onchange="ValueChanged(this);;">`

The function `ValueChanged` builds a URL with the order number and passes an Ajax request to another page through function `SendAjaxRequest` which collects the required data and then another function `SetValues` builds a table with the data on the page. Now, this function `SetValues` has the shortcut function `hotkeys` which adds the field dynamically.

Below is the javascript code

```
stopEvent = function(ffevent)
{
   var current_window = window;

   if(current_window.event) //window.event is IE, ffevent is FF
   {
      //IE
      current_window.event.cancelBubble = true; //this stops event propagation
      current_window.event.returnValue = false; //this prevents default (usually is what we want)
   }
   else
   {
      //Firefox
      ffevent.stopPropagation();
      ffevent.preventDefault();
   };
}

function validateAllInputBoxes(ffevent)
{


   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
      if(inputs[i].type === 'text')

         if(inputs[i].value === '') 
         {
            alert("form could not be sent one input text field is empty");
            stopEvent(ffevent);
         }


     var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Request"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Select GRN");
        stopEvent(ffevent);
    }


var inputFormDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
if (inputFormDiv<=1) {
    alert("Enter atleast one BIN Information");       
 stopEvent(ffevent);
}





}


function addRow() {
    var myName = document.getElementById("name");
    var age = document.getElementById("age");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= age.value;
}

 var deleteRow = function (link) {
     var row = link.parentNode.parentNode;
     var table = row.parentNode; 
     table.parentNode.removeChild(table); 
 }


//function deleteRow(obj) {
//    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
//    var table = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2");
//    table.deleteRow(index);
//}
function addTable() {
}
function load() {
    console.log("Page load finished");
}
function GetXmlHTTP() {
        //first check for IE:
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                var objXML = 0;
                try {
                        objXML = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(ex) {
                        try {
                                objXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch(ex) {
                                alert("AJAX: your browser does not support proper XMLHTTP");
                        }
                }
                return objXML;
        }

        //maybe Mozilla?
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                return new XMLHttpRequest();

        //unknown browser..
        alert("AJAX: unknown browser.");
        return 0;
} //end function GetXmlHTTP
/*
        this function send request to the given URL via
        GET method.
*/
function SendAjaxRequest(strURL) {
        //get xmlhttp component:
        var objXML = GetXmlHTTP();

        //got anything?
        if (!objXML)
                return false;

        //attach local callback function:
        objXML.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
                //ready?
                if (objXML.readyState == 4)
                {
                        //get status:
                        var status=objXML.status;

                        //maybe not successful?
                        if (status != 200)
                        {
                              //  alert("AJAX: server status " + status);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                //get response text:
                                var strResponse = objXML.responseText;

document.getElementById("myDynamicTable").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("myDynamicTable1").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("myDynamicTable3").innerHTML = "";




                                SetValues(strResponse);
                        }
                }
        }

        //send request:
        objXML.open("GET", strURL, true);
        objXML.send(null);
} //end function SendAjaxRequest


function SendAjaxRequest1(strURL) {
        //get xmlhttp component:
        var objXML = GetXmlHTTP();

        //got anything?
        if (!objXML)
                return false;

        //attach local callback function:
        objXML.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
                //ready?
                if (objXML.readyState == 4)
                {
                        //get status:
                        var status=objXML.status;

                        //maybe not successful?
                        if (status != 200)
                        {
                              //  alert("AJAX: server status " + status);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                //get response text:
                                var strResponse = objXML.responseText;
                                SetValues1(strResponse);
                        }
                }
        }

        //send request:
        objXML.open("GET", strURL, true);
        objXML.send(null);
} //end function SendAjaxRequest


function SendAjaxRequest2(strURL) {
        //get xmlhttp component:
        var objXML = GetXmlHTTP();

        //got anything?
        if (!objXML)
                return false;

        //attach local callback function:
        objXML.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
                //ready?
                if (objXML.readyState == 4)
                {
                        //get status:
                        var status=objXML.status;

                        //maybe not successful?
                        if (status != 200)
                        {
                              //  alert("AJAX: server status " + status);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                //get response text:
                                var strResponse = objXML.responseText;
                                SetValues2(strResponse);
                        }
                }
        }

        //send request:
        objXML.open("GET", strURL, true);
        objXML.send(null);
} //end function SendAjaxRequest


function ValueChanged(oDDL)
{
        var selectedValue = oDDL.value;


        if (selectedValue.length > 0)
        {
                var strURL = "RetrieveBIN.asp?value=" + selectedValue + "&ts=" + (new Date()).getTime();
               //SetValues("Loading...|Loading...|Loading...");
        rqstnumber = selectedValue;
                SendAjaxRequest(strURL);
        }
}

function ValueChangedDesc(oDDL)
{
        var selectedValue = oDDL.value;
   selectedValueBIN = oDDL.value;
        if (selectedValue.length > 0)
        {
                var strURL = "RetrieveDesc.asp?value=" + selectedValue + "&ts=" + (new Date()).getTime();
               //SetValues("Loading...|Loading...|Loading...");
                SendAjaxRequest1(strURL);
        }
}

function ValueChangedItem(oDDL)
{

  var xperia = document.forms["myForm"]["Request"].value;


//var binival = bini.value;

        var selectedValue = oDDL.value;
        if (selectedValue.length > 0)
        {
                var strURL = "RetrieveItem.asp?value=" + selectedValue + "&ts=" + (new Date()).getTime() + "&rqn=" + xperia + "&bin=" + selectedValueBIN;
//alert(strURL);

                //SetValues("Loading...|Loading...|Loading...");
                SendAjaxRequest2(strURL);
        }
}

function setTwoNumberDecimal(event) {
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(3);
}

function SetValues1(sRawData)
{
 var arrData = sRawData.split("|");
var oForm = document.forms["GetData"];



var txt =  document.activeElement.name;
var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
numb = numb.join("");

var elem = document.getElementById('1ItemDesc');

//elem.value = arrData[0];




var str = arrData[0];
var n = str.length;

if (n>0) {

//

//var myTableDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2");
//var table1 = document.createElement('TABLE');
//table1.border='1';
//var tableBody2 = document.createElement('TBODY');
//table1.appendChild(tableBody2);
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody1.appendChild(tr);


     var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text";   
input.setAttribute("size",'15');
input.setAttribute("autofocus",'True');
input.setAttribute("value", '');
input.setAttribute("name", serial+'ItemCode');
input.setAttribute("id", serial+'ItemCode');
//input.setAttribute("autofocus",'True');
input.setAttribute("required",'true');
input.setAttribute("data-parsley-required",'true');
input.onkeydown = function(){ValueChangedItem(this);};






var lblt = document.createTextNode('Item Code - ');

var td = document.createElement('TD');



td.appendChild(lblt);



      td.appendChild(input);
       tr.appendChild(td);



//alert(arrData[0]);

myTableDiv2.appendChild(table1);



//document.getElementById(serial+"ItemCode").focus();
//document.getElementById(serial+"ItemCode").focus();
//document.getElementById(serial+"ItemCode").focus();


var inputs1 = document.getElementById(serial+'ItemCode');

inputs1.focus();
inputs1.focus();
//inputs1.focus();



//for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
//  if (inputs[i].name = serial+'ItemCode') {
// alert(inputs[1].name);
//alert('arif');
//inputs[i].focus();

//break;
//  }
//   
//}



serial++;










} else  {



}

}



function SetValues2(sRawData)
{
 var arrData = sRawData.split("|");
var oForm = document.forms["GetData"];



//var txt =  document.activeElement.name;
//var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
//numb = numb.join("");

//var elem = document.getElementById('1ItemDesc');

//elem.value = arrData[0];




var str = arrData[0];
var n = str.length;

if (n>0) {

//

//var myTableDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2");
//var table3 = document.createElement('TABLE');
//table3.border='1';
//var tableBody3 = document.createElement('TBODY');
//table3.appendChild(tableBody3);
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody1.appendChild(tr);

var lblt = document.createTextNode('Item Desc - '+arrData[0]);
var td = document.createElement('TD');


td.style.fontSize = '12px';
td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
td.style.width = "100px";


     var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text";   
input.setAttribute("size",'15');

input.setAttribute("value", '');
input.setAttribute("name", serial+'Qty');
input.setAttribute("id", serial+'Qty');
input.setAttribute("required",'true');
input.setAttribute("data-parsley-required",'true');
input.setAttribute("data-parsley-type",'number');
input.onchange = setTwoNumberDecimal;



td.appendChild(lblt);
       tr.appendChild(td);
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody1.appendChild(tr);
var td = document.createElement('TD');

var lblt1 = document.createTextNode('Enter Quantity - ');
td.appendChild(lblt1);

      td.appendChild(input);
tr.appendChild(td);

//alert(arrData[0]);

myTableDiv2.appendChild(table1);




//var inputs = document.getElementsByName(serial+'Qty');


//for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
//  if (inputs[i].name = serial+'Qty') {
// alert(inputs[1].name);
//inputs[i].focus();
//break;
//  }
//   
//}


var inputs2 = document.getElementById(serial+'Qty');

inputs2.focus();
inputs2.focus();
//inputs2.focus();


serial++;

} else  {



}






//var allTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
//var ids = [];
//for (var tg = 0; tg< allTags.length; tg++) {
//    var tag = allTags[tg];
//    if (tag.id) {
//            ids.push(tag.id);
//     }   
//}
//alert(ids);

//var oformo = document.forms["1ItemCode");
//alert (oForm0);

//var valdesc = document.getElementById("");

}

function SetValues(sRawData)
{

//window.location.reload();

 var arrData = sRawData.split("|");
    var oForm = document.forms["GetData"];


//$('myDynamicTable2, table1').remove();


$('#myDynamicTable2').closest('tr').remove();

document.getElementById("myDynamicTable").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("myDynamicTable1").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("myDynamicTable3").innerHTML = "";
//document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2").innerHTML = "<br>";
//document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML = "";


serial=1;


var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
 var p=1;
var u=0;
u=parseInt(arrData[0]);
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');

table.border='1';
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);
for (var i=0; i<u; i++) {
   var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody.appendChild(tr);

  for (var j=0; j<1; j++) {
var lblt = document.createTextNode(arrData[p]);
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.style.fontSize = '12px';
td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
td.style.width = "80px";
            td.appendChild(lblt);
       tr.appendChild(td);
p++;
       }


    for (var j=0; j<1; j++) {
var lblt = document.createTextNode(arrData[p]);
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.style.fontSize = '12px';
td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
td.style.width = "120px";
            td.appendChild(lblt);
       tr.appendChild(td);
p++;
       }


    for (var j=0; j<1; j++) {
var lblt = document.createTextNode(arrData[p]);
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.style.fontSize = '12px';
td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
td.style.width = "50px";
            td.appendChild(lblt);
       tr.appendChild(td);
p++;
       }


     for (var j=0; j<1; j++) {
var lblt = document.createTextNode(arrData[p]);
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.style.fontSize = '12px';
td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
td.style.width = "70px";
td.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
            td.appendChild(lblt);
       tr.appendChild(td);
p++;
       }





  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody.appendChild(tr);





}


myTableDiv.appendChild(table);



var myTableDiv1 = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable1");
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border='1';
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);
for (var j=0; j<1; j++) {
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody.appendChild(tr);

      var btn = document.createElement('hyper'); 
var btnt = document.createTextNode('Press F7 to Add');
btn.appendChild(btnt);
btn.title = "Press F7 to Add";
btn.value = arrData[p];
var bin=1;




//----------shortcut.add("F7", function() {

hotkeys('f7', function(event, handler){
  // Prevent the default refresh event under WINDOWS system
  event.preventDefault() 



//  alert(serial+"BinLocation");
myTableDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2");
table1 = document.createElement('TABLE');
table1.border='1';
tableBody1 = document.createElement('TBODY');
table1.appendChild(tableBody1);


var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody1.appendChild(tr);

  for (var j=0; j<1; j++) {
      var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text";   
input.setAttribute("size",'15');
input.setAttribute("autofocus",'True');
input.setAttribute("value", '');
input.setAttribute("name", serial+'BinLocation');
input.setAttribute("id", serial+'BinLocation');
input.setAttribute("required",'true');
input.setAttribute("data-parsley-required",'true');
//input.required = required;
input.onkeydown = function(){ValueChangedDesc(this);};

      var btn = document.createElement('hyper'); 
var btnt = document.createTextNode('Delete');
btn.appendChild(btnt);
btn.title = "Delete";



//shortcut.add("f4", function() {deleteRow(this) });  

btn.onclick = function() {deleteRow(this)};
var lblt = document.createTextNode('Bin Location - ');
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.appendChild(lblt);
   td.appendChild(input);
       tr.appendChild(td);
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.appendChild(btn);
tr.appendChild(td);
bin++;
}
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody1.appendChild(tr);
myTableDiv2.appendChild(table1);



var inputs = document.getElementById(serial+'BinLocation');


inputs.focus();
inputs.focus();




serial++;



    }); 





var td = document.createElement('TD');
      td.appendChild(btn);
       tr.appendChild(td);
myTableDiv1.appendChild(table);
}   




}




function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Request"].value;
var e = document.forms["myForm"];
e=e.getElementsByTagName('input');
e=(e.length)+1;


   if (x == null || x == "") {
       alert("Select GRN");
       return false;
   }


if (e==2) {
     alert("2Number of fields is invalid");
       return false;
}

//alert(e) ; // 6

if ((e - 2) % 3 !== 0) {
     alert("Number of fields is invalid");
       return false;
}





}
```

I expect that without refreshing, any number of times the user selects the order and presses 'f7', the bin location fields should not duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please isolate only the relevant code

Comment: Actually the code is interrelated, so that's why I posted it.

Comment: @user3625561 You will have to try to untangle it a little bit then. I can tell you there's about 80% chance you will figure out the problem yourself if you try to create a concise example.